# TSQL Convert String to Year only

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I have the following table:

```
 SELECT * FROM [dbo].[Dimension_Game_Developer]
```

Table Schema:

[image]

Sample Data of select statement output:

[image]

I am trying to convert the string date as Year only date using the following:

```
 update [dbo].[Dimension_Game_Developer] 
 SET [Year_of_Release] = CAST([Year_of_Release] as DATE)
```

How would I make that change? Perhaps convert is better the CAST for this?

Comment: If it's a year, why store it as a string? the solution would be to fix the data type to an int, or if you want a the date of release than to a date. Not store it as an `varchar`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to cast `Year_of_Release` as `int` as shown below.

```
 update [dbo].[Dimension_Game_Developer] 
 SET [Year_of_Release] = CAST(Convert(Varchar(4), [Year_of_Release]) as int)
```

You can also convert it to `float`.

```
update [dbo].[Dimension_Game_Developer] SET [Year_of_Release] = 
CAST([Year_of_Release] as float)
```

To solve the issue permanently you should updated the datatype of column `Year_of_Release` to `int` and insert the value in the integer further.

To change the column datatype:

```
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[Dimension_Game_Developer] ALTER COLUMN Year_of_Release int;
```

Comment: Msg 245, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
Conversion failed when converting the varchar value '2009.0' to data type int.

Comment: It worked converting it to float:

 update [dbo].[Dimension_Game_Developer] 
 SET [Year_of_Release] = CAST([Year_of_Release] as float)

Comment: You could use the built in datepart function as follows
    select Datepart(YYYY, getdate())

Comment: @user1596914 Look the parameter here `Date` is not given rather it is a `varchar` type value contains `dot (.)` also.

Comment: @user1596914 From where you got `04.04.2020`? Please read the heading and sample data of `Year_of_Release` column. It is like `2009.0', `2008.0`, `2010.0`, etc in the varchar data type.

Comment: got it. select convert(int, substring('2009.0',1,4))

Answer (score 0):

to format values ​​without the need for cast and substring

use the function Call **Format** o **try_cast**

example:

```
DECLARE @d DATETIME = '10/01/2011';  

declare @tab table (StartDate date,  year varchar(6),val1  int,val2  int)
insert into @tab(StartDate,year,val1,val2) values('2014-02-15','2015.0',0,0)
insert into @tab(StartDate,year,val1,val2) values('2015-02-15','2016.0',0,0)
insert into @tab(StartDate,year,val1,val2) values('2016-02-15','2017.0',0,0)
insert into @tab(StartDate,year,val1,val2) values('2017-02-15','2018.0',0,0)

update @tab SET [val1] = FORMAT ( StartDate, 'yyyy'),[val2] =try_cast(year as decimal(18,0))

select * from @tab
```

these two functions can be found in the sql server documentation

Answer (score 0):

try  DatePart(year,CAST([Year_of_Release] as DATE)) Year